# New to React - using Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I just started learning react so please bare that in mind. I am trying to pull data from a public api using fetch and then place it in the "label" section inside of the setState. I am using chart.js so I am looking for label to take in an array of the five boroughs of new york city as per the api. The problem is the transfer of data between the fetch and the setState. I am able to fetch the data fine. I've tried a handful of things and would appreciate any help

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    chartData:{},
  }
}

componentWillMount(){
  this.getChartData();
}

getChartData(){
  // Ajax calls here

  fetch("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/27iv-9uub.json") 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    let boroughs = data.map((data) => {
      console.log(data.borough);
      return data.borough;
    })
    console.log(boroughs);
    return boroughs;
  })
  .catch(() => { 
    console.log("Promise Rejected"); 
  });
  let labels = boroughs;
  console.log(labels, 'test');
  this.setState({
    chartData:{
      labels: labels,
      datasets:[
        {
          label:'Population',
          data:[
            617594,
            1810450,
            153060,
            106519,
            105162
          ],
          backgroundColor:[
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's best practice to move your API calls to `componentDidMount` rather than `componentWillMount`. https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Answer (score 3):

You should set the state inside the `then function` of your API call and it is a good practice to use the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook when making ajax calls

```
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
  chartData:{},
}
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getChartData();
}

getChartData(){
  // Ajax calls here

fetch("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/27iv-9uub.json") 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    let boroughs = data.map((data) => {
      console.log(data.borough);
      return data.borough;
    })

    this.setState({
      chartData:{
        labels: boroughs,
        datasets:[
          {
            label:'Population',
            data:[
              617594,
              1810450,
              153060,
              106519,
              105162
            ],
            backgroundColor:[
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)'
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(() => { 
    console.log("Promise Rejected"); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, after doing this, my render function is not able to know what the state of this.state.chartData . Would there be a reason for this?

Comment: Can you share your `render` function?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, `this.setState` would need to be called inside the `then` that receives the data when the promise succeeds.

So, something like this:

```
fetch("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/27iv-9uub.json") 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({...});
    return data;
  })
  .catch(() => { 
    console.log("Promise Rejected"); 
  });
```

The fundamental issue here is that you don't have the `boroughs` until the promise is resolved in the `then` callback.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the response. When would you suggest setting boroughs if not inside the promise?

Comment: @BrianS that answer is quite a bit longer. In general, I would recommend using `redux` and then leveraging something like `redux-promise-middleware` to handle the `pending`, `fulfilled` and `rejected` states that can occur inside of a promise. This would further require hooking your component up to `redux`. I'd say if you're not using `redux` for a specific reason then you're *only option* is to do it inside of the resolution.

Comment: Awesome, much appreciated. I haven't dabbled with redux yet as I'm just starting out with react. I'll look more into that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in `constructor`

```
this.getChartData = this.getChartData.bind(this);
```